# Looking for old C64 game with "thriller" plot

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game

In the late 80s (1989...) I had a C64, I bought some magazine about videogames.

In one of this I read about a "thriller" game, in which you must discover the assassin in a house, I recall a magazine saying "If you don't take a forgotten knife in the kitchen, probably the killer will try to recover it". Some other details I recall:

- The game is set in a house
- The graphics are poor (very poor colors...)
- Was released for C64, I don't know if it was also released for other platforms
- In the game you are an investigator, there is no action, is more like an adventure/thriller
- For some things was similar to Maniac Mansion (the house closed..)
  but the quality is worst compared to Maniac Mansion

Does anyone know it?  It is *not* Maniac Mansion. It's not Friday the 13th

Comment: Can you remember what magazine it was ? English language or other ?

Comment: Probabyi zzap, italian language

Comment: Was it third-person like Maniac Mansion? Otherwise I’d guess maybe Crime Time?

Comment: Can be Crime time, but to confirm it, I have to know if is possible in crime time to take a knife

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe
[The Detective](https://www.lemon64.com/game/detective-game)

or
[Killed Until Dead](https://www.lemon64.com/game/killed-until-dead)

Comment: Is The Detective, i recognized it because there is a zzap review and talk about knives

Answer (score 4):

[Frankie Goes to Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankie_Goes_to_Hollywood_(video_game))?

[image: Frankie Goes to Hollywood]

> During the game, a murder takes place. All the rooms the player can visit contain clues in order to find the murderer. The clues are in pairs, helping eliminate suspects. For example, the player may be told "The killer is an atheist" and "Mr Somebody is a regular church-goer" - so Mr Somebody would be innocent.

Comment: Can be this, but must know if is possible to leave the knife in kitchen, so the suspect try to recover it

Answer (score 1):

Could be [Friday The 13th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESqUsmONzzI&t=4s), it has terrible graphics, a lot of running in and out of houses trying to find who is Jason in disguise, and you can pick up a knife as a weapon. It's actually a great little game.

Comment: No, is not because this is more on "action", my game is like an adventure, like Maniac Mansion but with awful quality, in the game you are an investigator/liutenent

Answer (score 1):

[Intrigue!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jItg45jC820) maybe?

It's not set in a house strictly though. But maybe you remember this wrong. But you are an investigator and there is a lot of plot twists.

Comment: No. Because the graphic had more colours